# MassTransit + Azure Service Bus authentication issue with Azure after upgrade to v8

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I've got a **dotnet 6 app** and I'm trying to **upgrade from MassTransit v7 to v8** but when I do it I'm facing an **Azure auth issue** (`Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed. 400, Bad Request`) in the Startup.cs, when trying to get a new token for the Azure KeyVault to build the app's configuration (`IConfiguration`).

```
config.AddAzureKeyVault(
  new SecretClient(new Uri("my-keyvault-uri"), new ManagedIdentityCredential("my-az-client-id")),
  new KeyVaultSecretManager());
```

This has always been working fine with MassTransit v7 but once I update it to 8.0.14, I start getting this authentication issue and cannot start the app. I **updated our NuGet packages** from

```
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="7.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="7.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" Version="7.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="7.3.0" />
```

To

```
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="8.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" Version="8.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="8.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Newtonsoft" Version="8.0.14" />
```

In case it helps, this is our **MassTransit core config**:

```
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    cfg.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busCfg) =>
      {
        busCfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=YYYYYY;SharedAccessKey=ZZZZZZ");
        ConfigureMassTransitBus(context, busCfg, true);
      });
    cfg.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();
});
```

```
private void ConfigureMassTransitBus(
   IBusRegistrationContext context,
   IBusFactoryConfigurator busCfg)
{
   busCfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
   busCfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my-endpoint", e => {
         e.ConfigureConsumer<MyClass>(context);
         e.UseMessageRetry(r => { r.Immediate(1); });
         e.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)));
   });
   busCfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
}
```

**What I tried so far (with no luck):**

- Carefully follow the MassTransit v7 to v8 migration guide
- Taken a look at similar issues on Stack overflow, Github, etc.
- Inject our ManagedIdentityCredentials as TokenService in the MassTransit host configuration
- Upgrade any other Azure identity related packages in the project
- Maybe it's related to how Mass transit injects the default IHostedService  but I still couldn't find the root cause

**I expect:**

- Everything to be working fine and Mass transit able to connect to Azure Service Bus correctly, with no issues when building the configuration from Azure KeyVault

Is someone experiencing a similar issue? I tried to review the MassTransit v7 to v8 migration carefully and also tried looking for similar issues but still no luck. Maybe I'm missing something and any help which points me towards possible issues would be more than welcome. Thank you very much for your time and help in advance!

*PS: if more details are needed, I'll be glad to share them. I just wanted to keep the description as simple as possible. *

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit v8 will automatically use the managed identity if you only specify the service bus namespace (no SharedAccessKey/KeyName in the connection string). Not sure what else is in your `ConfigureMassTransitBus` method, but the host can only be configured once (and calling it more than once throws away any previous host settings).

Comment: Hi Chris. First of all, thank you very much for your time and help. I've just updated the original post to include the `ConfigureMassTransitBus` method. It shouldn't configure host again.

The thing is the same configuration (even same connection string with SharedAccessKey and KeyName) works perfectly with MassTransit v7 but once we update it to v8, it stops working with the above exception.

Comment: Well, no reason why it wouldn't work. If you have a [support agreement](https://masstransit.io/support) you can contact support for technical guidance on upgrading.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! I'll take another look at the issue but in case I can't make it work, I'll take a look at the support agreements.